# FullCalendar does not seem to support Google-calendar-api v3?

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

FullCalendar has good support for public/private xml gdata feeds for Google-calendar-api-v2. However, this google-calendar-api version has been depreciated by google. Does Fullcalendar has any support to handle the json feed from Google-Calendar-Api-v3?? If so, can anybody share more details.

If gcal v3 is not current supported by fullcalendar, are there any plans to add to the support in the near future?

Thanks.

Comment: This document gives more information of the difference between verion3 and version2 of Google calendar api : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/migration

Comment: I don't think this plugin is actively developed by the author anymore. So don't count on support for v3 anytime soon. A better bet would be to make changes to the `fullcalendar.js` to make compatible with v3.